# cocos2d-x Get data from file (xxx.ccbi) failed

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

Anyone has the same trouble?It happpens when i want to load the ccbi file into the cocos2d-x project.I have debuged it .The resources path is correct.Maybe it's the version problem of cocosbuilde...Any help appreciated.

i just code as below ,here is the code link:
http://www.plungeinteractive.com/blog/2012/12/26/cocosbuilder-and-cocos2d-x-helloworld-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- May be it's because of version incompatibility between CocosBuilder and CCBReader as you said. If it is check your log for confirmation.
- In XCode if we do folder references for new files sometimes it doesn't includes it properly on next Build. Clear and Rebuilding solves this.
- One more time properly check Resource is correct path or not.

Comment: Yes,it's seems like a version problem.Thank you.